# Calculate $(M^T.\left(M.M^T\right)^{-1}.M{})_{i,j}$ for large sparse binary matrix $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse, projection-matrices

CONTEXT: I am a musician working on a algorithmic composition system. I need to find efficient algorithms to solve some matrix equations. I am not a mathematician or a student and direct answer is appreciated.

I have a very large sparse binary matrix M, where $M\in \{0,1\}^{n\times m}$. I am trying to calculate $N_{i,j}=(M^T.\left(M.M^T\right)^{-1}.M{})_{i,j}$.

EDIT: This is the matrix product of $M^T$ and the Moore-Penrose inverse of $M^T$.

$N_{i,j}$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and is too large to calculate completely -- I just need to find one element at a time.

I suspect there is a simple form for the elements of *N*. Can anyone show what $N_{i,j}$ looks like?

Thanks again.

**Bonus points**

I'll take what I can get, but it would be easier if the answer was in terms of these functions. Each row in *M* can be thought of a set of integers, e.g., the *i*th set is $\{x : M_{i,x} = 1\}$. I know many of the properties of these sets and can calculate numbers like these easily.

*j* belongs to set *i*: $M_{i,j}$

Size of a set (sum of a row): $J_{m}.M_{i}$

Number of sets *j* belongs to (sum of column): $J_{n}.M^T_{j}$

Size of the intersection of two sets (dot product of rows): $M_{i_{1}}.M_{i_{2}}$

etc.

Comment: So you're looking for the product of the Moore-Penrose inverse of a given matrix with the given matrix?

Comment: If that's what it's called, thank you. I'll look that up.

Comment: Yes, so I'm looking for the dot product of  $M^T$ and the Moore-Penrose inverse of $M^T$.

Comment: Do you need the entries to be exact or would approximations suffice?

Comment: It sure seems like the exact values are out there.  But an approximation might be useful.

Comment: I was asking because it looks hard to get exact entries. For an approximation, I would use the (thin) QR decomposition of $M$ and multiply with appropriate vectors to get just a few entries.

Comment: Forget the pseudoinverse. What you have is a projection matrix.

Answer (score 2):

As Rodrigo de Azevedo notes you are dealing with a projection matrix.

Your use of the notation $(MM^T)^{-1}$ implies that $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ has full rank, hence $n \leq m$.

Compute the $QR$ decomposition of $M^T \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, i.e. $M^T = QR$. Here $Q \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $R \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. $Q$ is orthonormal and $R$ is upper triangular with strictly positive diagonal entries. The cost is $O(mn^2)$ arithmetic operations and $O(mn+n^2)$ words of storage. Then
\begin{align} 
N = M^T(MM^T)^{-1} M &= QR (R^T Q^T Q R)^{-1}) R^T Q^T \\&= QR (R^T R)^{-1} R^T Q^T \\&= Q R R^{-1} R^{-T} R^T Q^T \\&= QQ^T
\end{align}
This approach is attractive if $n$ is small relative to $m$. You obviously have $O(m)$ words of storage available, but I can not tell if you have $O(mn)$ words available.

In any case, you will be able to compute $N_{ij}$ as $$N_{ij} = (Q^T e_i)^T (Q^T e_j),$$ i.e. by taking the inner product between the $i$th and the $j$th row of $Q$.

There are sparse codes available for computing a QR factorization. As far as I know there is no way to exploit that your entries are zeros and ones.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=M^T$ and $A^+$ be its Moore-Penrose inverse; we assume that $rank(A)=n\leq m$; then, according to  @J. M. is not a mathematician , we consider $Z=AA^+$ and we want to calculate $Z[p,q]$.

$Z$ is the orthogonal projection onto $im(A)$.

Step 1. We seek a basis $\{f_1,\cdots,f_n\}$ of the row space of $M$ and we orthogonalize it.

Step 2. $Z[p,q]=\sum_{k=1}^n<e_p,f_k><f_k,e_q>$, where $(e_i)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

That follows is a toy maple program with $n=15,m=100,p=14,q=35$. The rational $Z[p,q]$ is in $s$.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra);

roll := rand(0 .. 1);
M := Matrix(15, 100, proc (i, j) options operator, arrow; roll() end proc); Rank(M);
                               15
```

Practically, you don't calculate the first line of the following:

```
Z := Transpose(M) . (1/(M . Transpose(M))) . M:


R := RowSpace(M);
G := GramSchmidt(R, normalized);

p := 14; q := 35;
s := 0; for i to 15 do s := s+G[i][p]*G[i][q] end do; 

s-Z[p, q];  0


 s;  -14424929318699075225/1190467204823982047177
```